# Prevent Entity object from being inserted using Linq2Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity

If I have an Entity class that is instantiated, how can I prevent it from being inserted on `db.SubmitChanges()`? Assume that I need to create that object rather than creating a dummy object with the same properties.

```
var newPerson = new Person    //Entity Object
{
    FieldId = 3,
    Name = "John"
};
//....
db.SubmitChanges();    //Assume there are other items that will be upserted
```

How can you prevent Entity from tracking that object?

**Edit:**

As commented below, this was an error I was encountering:

After further testing, I realise the reason for the insertion was because I was modifying the initial Entity with a non-generic object, which causes 2 insertions (One for the object, and a new Person - from the example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't track that object unless you've set it to.

Just creating your object won't get it populated on the DB. 
You'll need to call `db.Persons.Add(newPerson)` or a similar method to attach it to a collection and then EF will start tracking your new object.

Comment: Apologies. You are right. After further testing, I realise the reason for the insertion was because I was modifying the initial Entity with a non-generic object, which causes 2 insertions (One for the object, and a new Person - from the example)

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you attach an entity to a dbContext, you need to specify the `State` property of that entity so EF knows whether to insert, update or delete that entity. For EF to not update the database, you can explicitly set its state to `Unchanged`.